# Es posible llamar a un item dentro de un contextmenu?

Tags: c#

estoy buscando información sobre como llamar a un item dentro de un contextmenu en un programa viejo que deseo manipular, se que es posible a través de Sendmessage y WM_COMMAND pero no tengo idea de como encontrar el ID del elemento de menú. Buscando mucho me encontré con un post en ingles donde el usuario "[ScottMcP-MVP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173614/finding-handle-for-a-button-in-the-window-of-another-program/23173692#:%7E:text=A%20button%20is,the%20same%20message.)" menciona que las barras de herramientas haces eso pero lamentablemente no se explico o yo no entendí como lograr obtener el ID del Item.

No estoy pidiendo código ni nada de eso, solo una guía porque esto es algo que nunca había echo y no me doy maña para buscar correctamente la información... Desde ya muchas gracias!!!

EDITADO:
Tengo un emulador de videjuegos viejo y necesito controlar una de de las opciones que aparece en su contextmenu o menustrinp (Aclaro misma opción aparece en ambos lados) el asunto que haciendo pruebas con el bloc de notas si pude encontrar en ID del item, pero en el programa parece que no lo posee y no se como afrontar ese problema, he leído en algún comentario por la web que no es necesario invocar el item del menú y que se puede llamar directamente, pero de eso no se nada mas que lo que explicó.

Una captura de las pruebas con bloc de notas y las que hice con el emulador y dejo el link del emulador por si alguien le interesa ayudarme!

Bloc de notas item Buscar...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Emulador mensaje WM_COMMAND extraño!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Link del emulador:
https://mega.nz/file/tYoFiahB#SG9q6r88v-VfHVZuN_15LpVX06bh7SUYQZFWLPnC8O0

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: LISTO! Ahora si esta claro lo que necesito!

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Hola Arcanis, lo que pasa es que no he posteado codigo por la razón de que no quiero que la persona que me ayude me arregle el codigo para mi, sino es que busco que me expliquen la lógica sobre como atacar este problema, osea si un item en contextmenu no es un control y no tiene ID sino que es una pintura que tipo de estrategia se utiliza en esos casos, pero bueno si es necesario código entonces lo escribiré y lo publicare mas tarde! Gracias!!!!